# IE certificate issue in Weblogic server application

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, weblogic11g

Deployed the project in weblogic server 10.3 in local. The application works fine in Firefox but in IE says error

> There is a problem with this website's security certificate

after click the login.

Used J_Security_Check for login.

even clicked continue this web site also not help

I am using the default certificates that come with weblogic installation. I have not generated any private keys or certificates.

I am new to the web logic server.
Please let me know we need to do any configurations in Web logic server to work in IE

or how to solve the issue.

[image: There is a problem certificate]

Answer (score 1):

Method-1 Install the certificate

```
1. In Windows Internet Explorer, click Continue to this website (not recommended).

2. A red Address Bar and a certificate warning appear.
3. Click the Certificate Error button to open the information window.
4. Click View Certificates, and then click Install Certificate.
5. On the warning message that appears, click Yes to install the certificate.
```

Method-2 Add website to Security zone

Check this : [Add sites to security zone](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-zones-adding-removing-websites#1TC=windows-7)

Method-3 Disable certificate check.

```
1. To clear the certificate error, go to Tools --> Internet Options from the menu.
2. Click on the Advanced tab and scroll down to the security section. Clear the boxes for: "Check for publisher's certificate revocation" and "Check for server certificate revocation".
3. Click Apply and Ok.
4. Attempt to reload the page by clicking the Refresh button at the end of the address bar or by pressing the F5 key. Your page should now load as expected.
```

Personally i don't recommend Method-3. If you are facing the issue in development environment, i suggest you ignore it :)